# Why was my question migrated to Super User?

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm not complaining or mad - just confused. The reason for Server Fault is "For System Administrators and Desktop Professionals - which I am." My question seemed to me to be related to a "desktop professional's" role: https://superuser.com/questions/307873/which-quickbooks-7-enterprise-edition-do-i-have. Why was it migrated?

Please help me understand this. :)

Comment: one quick comment. There's no need to sign your posts, in fact it's strongly discouraged. Your sig block is posted with each question or answer you give, so anything else is just noise.

Comment: QuickBooks has a **strong** stigma of being end users' software and not closely coupled to system administration (in fairness, QB is the best of the *cheap crap accounting software*). Five users thought SU was a better fit, that's all it takes.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the point on the signature too, I'll keep that in mind. When I think "desktop professional", I have always thought of someone doing advanced technical work (including software installation). I must be in the minority. But this is a good discussion, both the answers and these comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question wasn't about administering, managing or supporting servers, desktops or related gear. It was about an application. Whether that's an "enterprise" edition or not is really quite irrelevant. If I remember correctly I actually voted it as "not constructive" because I don't believe it belongs on SU either, although I appear to be in the minority on that.

Answer (score 3):

Because just lower down in that FAQ it says "and it is not about … General personal computer troubleshooting" - and because 5 separate users thought superuser would be likely to provide better answers.